Can I change the interval of a glib.timeout_seconds_add loop from within the loop?
I have a glib.timeout loop:
glib.TimeoutSecondsAdd(showstat, func() bool {

can I change the timeout interval from within the loop?
(this is written in Go/gotk3)
I'm updating data rates in a display, but if I start using too much memory I would like to increase the loop interval, otherwise I just have to stop updating the stats.

I just ran a test, and the answer appears to be no.
